# intellij Querk or not

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I just started using intellij and I just noticed that when it sets up your initial res folders it does not include the Drawable.  I know that I can just add the folders no big deal, I was just a wandering why.   Then again maybe I have done something wrong.

Comment: "Drawable" folder?  What's that?  I've used IntelliJ for eight years and never had to have such a thing.  That might explain why it's not a meaningful default.  Can you explain what it is?

Comment: @duffymo, it's Android project specific folder.

Answer (score 1):

As you can notice from the log in [this video](http://www.screenr.com/dWd8), `res/drawable*` folders are created by Android SDK tools. It's not handled by IDEA, it's a feature of Android SDK.

Comment: I agree so I was surprised to see it not created in the res

Comment: Reinstalling Android SDK may help.